# How to calculate total energy consumption using Cooja

Tags: contiki, energy, cooja

I'm working with wireless sensor network lead to evaluate its performance in my work.  I want to measure the latency and  total energy consumption to find the remaining energy in each node. So my problem is that I have some values of `tx rx cpu cpu_idle`  and I don't how to use them to calculate what I need. I found some rules that take the calculation but i don't understand exactly how to apply it in my case.

Energy consumed in communication:
[image]

Energy consumed by CPU:

[image]

What is the meaning of 32768, and why do we use this number? Is it a standard value?

Comment: Where did you find that case study, please declare the source of these pictures or paper. In general, there aren't any rules for a good energy calculation. It depends on switched on peripherals, used processor, speed, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The powertrace output is printed in timer ticks.

- `tx` - the number of ticks the radio has been in transmit mode (`ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT`)
- `rx` - the number of ticks the radio has been in receive mode (`ENERGEST_TYPE_LISTEN`)
- `cpu` - the number of ticks the CPU has been in active mode (`ENERGEST_TYPE_CPU`)
- `cpu_idle` - the number of ticks the CPU has been in idle mode (`ENERGEST_TYPE_LPM`)

The elements of the pair `tx` and `rx` are exclusive, as are `cpu` and `idle` - the system can never be in both modes at the same time. However, other combinations are possible: it can be in `cpu` and in `tx` at the same time, for example. The sum of `cpu` and `idle` is the total uptime of the system.

The duration of timer a tick is platform-dependent and defined as the `RTIMER_ARCH_SECOND` constant. 32768 ticks per second is a typical value of this constant - that's where the number in your equation comes from. For example:

```
ticks_in_tx_mode = energest_type_time(ENERGEST_TYPE_TRANSMIT);
seconds_in_tx_mode = ticks_in_tx_mode / RTIMER_ARCH_SECOND;
```

To compute the **average current consumption** (in *milliamperes*, *mA*), multiply each of `tx`, `rx`, `cpu`, `cpu_idle` with the respective current consumption in that mode in *mA* (obtain the values from the datasheet of the node), sum them up, and divide by `RTIMER_ARCH_SECOND`:

```
current = (tx * current_tx_mode + rx * current_rx_mode + \
          cpu * current_cpu + cpu_idle * current_idle) / RTIMER_ARCH_SECOND
```

To compute the **charge** (in *millicoulumbs*, *mC*), multiply the average current consumption with the duration of the measurement (node's uptime) in seconds:

```
charge = current * (cpu + cpu_idle) / RTIMER_ARCH_SECOND
```

To compute the **power** (in *milliwats*, *mW*) multiply the average current consumption with the voltage of the system, for exampe, 3 volts if powered from a pair of AA batteries:

```
power = current * voltage
```

Finally, to compute the **energy consumption** (in *millijoules*, *mJ*), multiply the power with the duration in seconds or multiply the charge with the voltage of the system:

```
energy = charge * voltage
```

The first formula above computes the energy consumption for communications; the second one: for computation.

This [site](http://thingschat.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/contiki-os-using-powertrace-and.html) might be helpful to break down the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

32768 Hz or 32, 768 kHz this is of MSP430F247 Microcontroller frequency, for specifics are Active mode: 32iuA @ 3 v / 1 MHz or 1x10 6 Hz and Low Power mode = 1 uA @ 3V /32768 Hz